# Как с помощью javascript отследить наличие файла .js?

Tags: javascript

Есть игра (т.е. скоро будет), в которой после прохождения уровня подгружается следующий файл .js с необходимыми данными. Например, есть 2 файла - 1.js и 2.js. При прохождении первого уровня с помощью

```
lv = lv + 1;
var _script = document.createElement("script");
 _script.src = "levels/" + lv + ".js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(_script);
```

подгружается 2.js. Так вот, как можно отследить, что 3.js НЕ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ и выдать при этом сообщение. Пробовал через try catch - не помогает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, как вариант

```
$.ajax({
    url:'somescript.js',
    success:function(){
        alert('exists');
    },
    error:function(){
        alert('no such file');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/knes/j2npbwbq/

**Обновление**

http://jsfiddle.net/knes/qckw3yjf/ - без jquery.

Конечно, нельзя, так как JS работает на стороне клиента, соответственно он не может знать, что происходит на сервере.
Чу-у-уть-чуть более мягкий способ - обращаться к php скрипту (какому-нибудь экшену контроллера), опять же, по аяксу и спрашивать у него наличие того или иного файла, в случае наличия подключать. Так у вас не будет вылезать ошибка в консоли.

Comment: Я имел в виду без ajax и без jQuery. В общем, я понял - в любом случае в консоли появляется "Failed to load resourse". Хоть jQuery, хоть чистый js. Отследить onerror можно, но запретить вообще загрузку несуществующего файла - никак нельзя.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: @knes, изначально прога была написана с использованием php, jQuery и ajax, решил сделать независимую от сервера конструкцию - только html и javascript. Все ок, ведь не каждый же будет открывать консоль и наблюдать за возможными ошибками. ))))

Comment: @knes, при открытии консоли - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 

То, что я хотел узнать, я узнал - с помощью js невозможно отследить отсутствие файла на сервере. Можно только отловить object.onerror  и принять определенные действия, хотя в консоли будет висеть сообщение об ошибке. Я просто надеялся, что есть похожее на "@some_code" как в php ))))

Answer (score 0):

Можно в каждый файл добавить код:

```
1.js
    ...
    var script_1_loaded = true;
    ...

2.js :
    ...
    var script_2_loaded = true;
    ...
```

Если скрипт N загрузился, переменная `script_N_loaded` будет `true`.
Главный скрипт должен проверять, доступна ли переменная. Если переменная не инициализирована, значит такого скрипта нет.

Comment: Скрипт с N=3 не может иметь переменную script_N_loaded, потому что файла 3.js вообще не существует.

Comment: А что мешает в основном скрипте хранить количество уровней? Либо загружать его динамически, выполняя асинхронный запрос к серверу, а скрипт на сервере вычислит количество файлов в заданном каталоге.

Comment: @DarkGenius, откуда основному скрипту знать, сколько уровней существует? Админ может добавлять уровней, сколько ему угодно. Асинхронный ajax требует наличия php-обработчика. Я бы хотел обойтись без ajax. 

До этого программа так и работала - на ajax-запросах. Все было ок. Теперь захотелось без ajax. Возможно ли это?

Comment: @Deus, проблематично создать дополнительный обработчик?
Можно навесить событие  _script.onload, в котором callback-функция будет проставлять признак успешной загрузки. А неуспешная загрузка будет детектиться с помощью функции, вызываемой по таймауту: если при вызове функции признак успешной загрузки не установлен, считать загрузку неуспешной.

Comment: @DarkGenius, 

_script.onload работает только после добавления скрипта в DOM:

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(_script);

_script.onload = function(){

}

но document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(_script); уже выводит ошибку, потому что данного файла не существует

Comment: Суть проблемы непонятна. Если скрипта нет, значит он не загрузится. В каждом скрипте можно инициализировать какие-то переменные или вызывать onload. Главный скрипт будет ждать некоторое время. Если переменные не появились, или код onload не вызвался, значит скрипта не существует.